# HttpClient throws HttpRequestException under load

Tags: .net, http, dotnet-httpclient

We are load testing a .NET web application (hosted in IIS) that communicates with various 
services. 
However, some time after test is started and the load increased, the `HttpClient` starts throwing errors at us:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond <ip_address_here>:443
```

The investigation with Wireshark showed these requests didn't even reach the load balancer - it shows TCP resets when that situation occur. The approximate timeframe is 90-100 seconds, and I'm thinking it has to do with the fact that default HttpClient timeout is 100 seconds (and we haven't modified it). 
We use one `HttpClient` instance for all the communication with this particular service, so it gets accessed in a concurrent manner. 
We construct it in `BackendClient` class:

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
```

use it in `BackendClient` methods:

```
var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

and then dispose of it in `BackendClient.Dispose` code. 
This problem only shows under load, we can't reproduce it anywhere else. 
Anyone familiar with this? I'm sure there's some setting that we missed. 
The only option I'm seeing is to attach a traceListener and see what it shows